# Appending to an existing string

Tags: ruby

To append to an existing string this is what I am doing.

```
s = 'hello'
s.gsub!(/$/, ' world');
```

Is there a better way to append to an existing string.

Before someone suggests following answer lemme show that this one does not work

```
s = 'hello'
s.object_id
s = s + ' world'
s.object_id
```

In the above case object_id will be different for two cases.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

You can use `<<` to append to a string in-place.

```
s = "foo"
old_id = s.object_id
s << "bar"
s                      #=> "foobar"
s.object_id == old_id  #=> true
```

Comment: How do you do s <<! "bar", as in to modify the state of the object? concat!("bar") doesn't work...

Comment: @RainbowPony As my answer shows, `<<` already modifies the state of the object. So does `concat`.

Comment: Not always: irb(main):038:0> widget.notes.where(:author_id => a).first.message.concat("Potato")
=> "Y halo thar! =DPotato"
irb(main):039:0> widget.notes.where(:author_id => a).first.message=> "Y halo thar! =D"  # widget is an instance of Widget. It can have notes. message is attr_accessible.

Comment: @RainbowPony Yes, always. In your case you get back the unchanged string because `widget.notes.where(:author_id => a).first` presumably returns a new object each time, which will have its own independent string.

Comment: Ah. I just asked a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989619/ruby-concat-or-how-to-modify-state-of-object-elegantly thanks for the help!

Answer (score 61):

you can also use the following:

```
s.concat("world")
```

Comment: `<<` should be chainable as well, since it returns the string.

Comment: Indeed - and << is also shorter to write AND looks similar to the C++ cout variant. << is beauty!

Comment: Note: this modifies the original string. Use carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Can I ask why this is important?

I know that this is not a direct answer to your question, but the fact that you are trying to preserve the object ID of a string might indicate that you should look again at what you are trying to do.

You might find, for instance, that relying on the object ID of a string will lead to bugs that are quite hard to track down.

Comment: Maybe to modify parameters by reference? (which is probable bad design in a full-fledged oop language)

Comment: Or just to avoid creating too many new objects? That's perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Surely if you modify a string in place and a new object is created, then the old object gets garbage collected?  Should we really be worrying about the number of String objects we create?

Comment: @Shadowfirebird Maybe he's writing a method that gets called 1000's of times a second and doesn't want to bog down his garbage collector with a bunch of strings.

Answer (score 2):

Yet an other way:

```
s.insert(-1, ' world')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
fist_segment = "hello,"
second_segment = "world."
complete_string = "#{first_segment} #{second_segment}"
```