# Ruby concat! or <<! (how to modify state of object elegantly)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, operators

Is there a more elegant way to do this:

```
widget.notes.where(:author_id => a).first.message= widget.notes.where(:author_id => a).first.message << "Potato"
```

For example, the following do not work:

```
widget.notes.where(:author_id => a).first.message << "Potato"
widget.notes.where(:author_id => a).first.message <<! "Potato"
```

Respectively not modifying, or returning an error (as there is no

```
<<!
```

operator)

key: widget is an instance of Widget. Widgets can have notes. Notes have an attr_accessible for :message. 'a' is just a user instance.

Comment: (widget.notes.where(:author_id => a).first.message << "Potato").save! doesn't work...

Comment: That's because it returns a string... derp... maybe I should write a proc for it as its probably not built in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem of `<<` not modifying the string in-place - it does modify the string in-place. `<<` might not have a `!` in its name, but it still acts like a bang-method. You can see this easily if you replace `<<` with a call to `gsub!` (which does have a `!` in its name) in your example code: it won't make a bit of difference.

In your case you get back the unchanged string because widget.notes.where(:author_id => a).first presumably returns a new object each time, which will have its own independent string.

Further, if `message` corresponds to a database column, not an instance variable, I'm not sure whether calling mutating methods on it will even work as it would circumvent calling ActiveRecord's (or whichever ORM you're using) setter methods. Using `+=` might be your safest bet here.

This should work as you want:

```
note = widget.notes.where(:author_id => a).first
note.message += "Potato"
note.save
```

Comment: pjumble just deleted a comment which was perfect! : widget.notes.where(:author_id => a).first.tap { |w| w.message += "Potato" }.save!